# Find all homomorphisms $φ : \mathbb{Z} → \mathbb{Z}$. Which of these homomorphisms are isomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, group-homomorphism

I'm currently working in the following excercise:

> Find all homomorphisms $φ : \mathbb{Z} → \mathbb{Z}$. Which of these homomorphisms are isomorphisms?

If $\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$, then would be infinite homomorphisms fulfilling the homomorphism property? I know that an isomorphism is a biyective application of $φ$ but I'm not sure about my reasoning about homomorphisms by first.

Thanks in advance for any hint or help and for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: What kind of homomorphisms are you talking about? Of rings or of modules? In any case it will help you to write down the definition of a homomorphism.

Comment: Hint: $\phi(n) = n\cdot \phi(1)$

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Given the tags, I guess group homomorphisms.

Comment: @Wojowu Indeed, you are right. Missed that. Still writing down the definition will solve the problem. Especially after Jakobian's comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image of a map $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ is defined by the image $\varphi(1)$, because $1$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}$. For example: if $\varphi(1)=3$, then $\varphi(4)=\varphi(1+1+1+1)=\varphi(1)+\varphi(1)+\varphi(1)+\varphi(1)=12$, so the map becomes multiplication with $3$. Thus we have for each $n$ a group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$. In order to be a group isomorphism the generator $1$ has to be mapped to a generator, which can only be $1$ and $-1$, so we have $2$ isomorphisms. Does this help?