# All homorphisms that are isomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

My question was addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241722/find-all-homomorphisms-%CF%86-mathbbz-%E2%86%92-mathbbz-which-of-these-homomorphis). The answers claims there are two isomorphisms, but I think that is not correct (or I really think I might be wrong, but don't see why).

The homorphisms $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $\varphi(n)=n\varphi(1)$, that is multiplication by $\varphi(1)$. Since we have the additive group, the identity is $0$. Hence the kernel is given by:
$$\text{ker} \varphi=\{a\in \mathbb{Z}| \varphi(a)=0\}$$

But $\varphi(a)=a\varphi(1)$, then if $a=0\rightarrow \varphi(a)=0 \quad \forall \varphi(1)$, that is all homorphisms are also isomorphisms, which to me makes sense, because ultimately $\varphi$ is a linear map, which is injective and surjective, hence an isomorphism.

I'd like to know if there is a flaw in my reasoning, and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241722/find-all-homomorphisms-%CF%86-mathbbz-%E2%86%92-mathbbz-which-of-these-homomorphis) is correct, and if so, where is my flaw how to get to that answer using the kernel.

Comment: It’s not true that all homomorphisms are isomorphisms. What you’ve shown, with some cleaning up, is that if $\varphi(1)$ is nonzero then $\varphi$ is injective. But you forgot the case $\varphi(1) = 0$ and you haven’t addressed surjectivity.

Comment: Actually you haven’t even computed the kernel in any case. You’ve written the implication in the wrong direction; to compute the kernel you want to start with $\varphi(a) = 0$ and deduce the possible values of $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think bringing in the technical language of kernels has obscured the point. An isomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ is a bijective homomorphism. You're right that the homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ are exactly the linear maps; so in order to count the isomorphisms **we want to count the bijective linear maps**.

A little thought shows that *not* every linear map is bijective. For example:

- $x\mapsto 0\cdot x$ is not injective.
- $x\mapsto -2\cdot x$ is not surjective.

So we're left with the question:

> For which $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ is the map $x\mapsto z\cdot x$ a bijection?

And it's not hard to see the answer:

> $z=1$ and $z=-1$, so there are indeed exactly two isomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ - or more snappily, exactly two *automorphisms of* $\mathbb{Z}$.

---

How does this interact with the language of kernels?

Well, calculating the kernel of $f$ will address *half* of the question of whether $f$ is a bijection: specifically, $f$ is injective iff $ker(f)=\{0\}$. However, it does *not* tell you anything about surjectivity. So you can't fully understand the isomorphisms just by thinking about kernels.

(Actually that's not quite true: for maps from a *finite* set to itself, injectivity implies surjectivity - and so a self-homomorphism of a finite group is an automorphism iff its kernel is $\{0\}$. However, that doesn't apply in the $\mathbb{Z}$ case.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since $\varphi(a) = \varphi(1)a$ for all $a \in \mathbb Z$, we have that if $a = 0$ then $\varphi(a) = 0$, that is, we have if $a = 0$ then $a \in \ker \varphi$. But this doesn't mean that $\ker \varphi = \{0\}$, just $\ker \varphi \supseteq \{0\}$.

Comment: If $\varphi(1)\neq0$, then $\text{ker} \varphi =\{0\}$. Would that be a true statement?

Comment: @Schach21 Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

$\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z},\ x\mapsto 5x$ is injective but not surjective